# Chef: Kitchen Converge cannot find local cookbook dependency

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, test-kitchen

I have 2 local cookbooks. One is called `golang_app` and the other is called `test_go_web_app`. `test_go_web_app` depends on `golang_app` and runs `golang_app::default` by doing `include_recipe 'golang_app::default'` in its `default.rb`....

I am trying to add `golang_app` as `test_go_web_app`'s dependency... Right now, `test_go_web_app`'s Berksfile looks like:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'golang_app', path: '../golang_app'

metadata
```

However, when running `kitchen converge`, I am getting:

```
Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
   ----------------------------------
   Cookbook golang_app not found. If you're loading golang_app from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata

   Cookbook Trace:
   ---------------
     /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test_go_web_app/recipes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'

   Relevant File Content:
   ----------------------
   /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test_go_web_app/recipes/default.rb:

     1>> include_recipe 'golang_app::default'
     2:
```

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the Berksfile line, you also need to add `depends 'golang_app'` to the `metadata.rb` for test_go_web_app. Also make sure the Berksfile is right next to the Kitchen config file in your folder structure.